# Second of two fragments only displayed in landscape mode: Layout bug or lifecycle issue?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-orientation

I want to be able to dynamically change the content of two fragments, the one on the left (in landscape mode) resp. on top (in portrait mode) playing videos (a `VideoView`) and the one on the right (landscape) resp. at the bottom (portrait) showing text (a `TextView`). So I created a `MainActivity.java` which only displays the layout container (`activity_main.xml`), a `VideoFragment.java` and its layout file (`fragment_video.xml`), and a `TextFragment.java` and its layout file (`fragment_text.xml`). Since I want the videos (which are cut into a square shape) to be displayed in a square (same size in landscape and portrait), I overwrote `LinearLayout`'s `onMeasure` method in `SquareLayout.java`.

Now the (not so) funny (anymore) thing is that everything works fine in landscape orientation, yet in portrait mode the `TextView` is not displayed. (I have to add that the orientation change is "implemented" through the "lazy" `onConfigurationChanged` method of the two fragments.) I tend to think that there is a bug in the nested `LinearLayout`s and their width and height parameters, but I could not yet figure out (by changing these parameters) where exactly the bug would be located. I also tried to visualize the usage of lifecycle methods (with `Toast`s) and things seemed as one would expect, i.e. while `onConfigurationChanged` was in place, it was used during orientation change and `onPause` and `onResume` were not, and while `onConfigurationChanged` was not in place, `onPause` and `onResume` were used. That is to say that the `TextView` existed. Any ideas anyone? Thanks!

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package org.myPackage.myApp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }       
}
```

VideoFragment.java

```
package org.myPackage.myApp;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoFragment extends Fragment {

    VideoView videoView;
    int position;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        videoView = (VideoView) getView().findViewById(R.id.video);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.clip);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.start();  
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        position = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        videoView.seekTo(position);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);        
    }
}
```

TextFragment.java

```
package org.myPackage.myApp;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text, container,
            false));            
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        textView.setPadding(12, 6, 6, 12);
        textView.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

SquareLayout.java

```
package org.myPackage.myApp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class SquareLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public SquareLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = widthSize < heightSize ? widthSize : heightSize;
        int finalMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size,
            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(finalMeasureSpec, finalMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="org.myPackage.myApp.VideoFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="org.myPackage.myApp.TextFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <org.MyPackage.MyApp.SquareLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</org.MyPackage.MyApp.SquareLayout>
```

fragment_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.MyPackage.MyApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.MyPackage.MyApp.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but I give you some idea I have. Maybe you could create two copys of your activity_main.xml (I think the behaviour of your app is the same in both orientations), one with a Vertical LinearLayout and other with Horizontal LinearLayout, each one in /res/layout-port and /res/layout-land.

Comment: I had tried this yesterday - without any success. Tried it again today - with the same result, until I started playing with the `android:configChanges` in `AndroidMainfest.xml`. When I remove either `orientation` or `screenSize` it starts working, but it breaks continuous playing of my video ... So the problem gets  shifted elsewhere. I will try with `setRetainInstance`. Thanks.